# Why view with column alias is not insertable?

Tags: mariadb

```sql
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `stars` integer, 
  `title` varchar(255)
);

CREATE VIEW projects_view AS SELECT *, title AS name FROM projects;
```

When I try to insert something:

```sql
INSERT INTO `projects_view` (`name`) VALUES ('Name');
```

I get: `ERROR 1471 (HY000): The target table projects_view of the INSERT is not insertable-into`

But this works in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Does your view have three columns? Or why do you use `SELECT *, title`?

Comment: @Progman This is a simplified version of the table, the real has many more columns. But explicitly enumerating columns instead of `*` also do not work.

Comment: MariaDB, but looks like this will also not work here too.
I have found https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inserting-and-updating-with-views/#inserting-with-views
But is `columnA AS columnB` considered "derived column"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot insert because by using `select *` you have *two* references in the view to a single column.

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html) a view is not insertable where

> Multiple references to any column of a base table (fails for INSERT, okay for UPDATE, DELETE)

It should work if you name each column:

```
CREATE VIEW projects_view AS 
SELECT stars, title as name FROM projects;
```

[Fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=343d83be9b281df9efceb05b8c95271c)